# How to use Wireshark to capture HTTP data for a device on the same network as me

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, wireshark, sniffing

I've setup a wifi router and connect my Kali Linux laptop and my Android mobile phone to it.
I do know the password already (I've set it up) and I want to sniff all the data coming and going to the Android device. Wireshark is going to be run through my kali Linux box and my WiFi device is set on monitor mode already.

When I create a .cap file using `airodump-ng` I do see that data is captured. When I try to browse the cap file using Wireshark I don't see any HTTP traffic in it.

So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to capture HTTP traffic when you are on the same WiFi network as your target device but you are running Wireshark (or airodump) from the source device?
2. If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should [check this man page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN), but as far as I understand it you need to be in promiscuous mode and not monitor mode to be able to inspect the packets payload.

Monitor mode of your WiFi card will allow you to capture packets outside your SSID but I suppose at this point it's useless since you're anyway already on the same network.

Comment: Honestly I tried following the man page more than once but I can't find an answer to my questions.
I wanted to create a scenario where an outside device will bruteforce or find the wiif password, then enter the network by connecting to the router.
Once its inside it will monitor other devices to sniff their browsing data.
Thanks for the monitor tip :)